# What insight is there on negative number bases?

Tags: number-theory

I don't really have much to say, other than that I was curious about how negative number bases work, and I was wondering if I could get some insight on how to understand them.

I know how to convert negative base numbers to base 10, but have no clue as to how to write a base 10 number to an arbitrary negative base, at least not easily.

I have also noticed that there seems to be 2 ways to write every number in a negative base, for example $37_{10}$ can be written as $177_{-10}$ or $-43_{-10}$ and think there could be some way to use that to your advantage, although I still haven't gotten anywhere myself.

Comment: I've tweaked your notation a bit - "$a_b$" is a clearer way to write "$a$ interpreted as a base-$b$ notation." Separately, I don't see why this notation-multiplicity would be advantageous - can you elaborate on why you expect that?

Comment: You can google and read up on them. Wikipedia's article is a good starting point. Upshot: just as any number can be unique written as $n = \sum_{k=0}^m a_k b^k$ then for a positive $b$ and all $a_k:0\le a_k<b$ we can uniquely write it as $n=\sum_{k=0}^{m;m+1}c_k (-b)^k$ with $0\le c_k< b$.  You can verify be haveing $c_k = a_k + 1$ for all even $k$ and $c_k = b-a_k$ for odd $k$.  Example:  $4315_6 = 4\times 6^3 + 3\times 6^2 + 1\times 6 + 5 = (6-2)\times 6^3 + 3\times 6^2 + (6-5)\times 6 + 5 = 6^4 - 2\times 6^3+4\times 6^2 - 6\times 6 + 5 =(-6)^4 +2\times (-6)^3 + 3\times (-6)^2 +5=12305_{-6}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know how to convert negative base numbers to base 10, but have no clue as to how to write a base 10 number to an arbitrary negative base, at least not easily.

Write it to the positive absolute value base first.  subtract the odd terms from $|b|$ and carry to even terms.

Example:  To write $1234$ in base $-6$.

$1234 = 205\times 6 + 4 =$

$34\times 6^2 + 1\times 6 + 4=$

$5\times 6^3 + 4\times 6^2 + 1\times 6 + 4 =5414_6$.

$=5\times 6^3 + 4\times 6^2 + 1\times 6 + 4$

$=(6-1)\times 6^3 + 4\times 6^2 + (6-5)\times 6 + 4=$

$=6^4 - 6^3 + (4+1)\times 6^2 -5\times 6 + 4 = $

$(-6)^4 + (-6)^3 + 5\times (-6)^2 + 5\times(-6) + 4 = 11554_{-6}$

With practice we can do it directly.

$1234= -205(-6) + 4=$

$(35\cdot (-6)+5)(-6) + 4=$

$35(-6)^2 + 5(-6) + 4=$

$(-5\times -6 + 5)(-6)^2 + 5(-6) + 4=$

$-5(-6)^3 + 5(-6)^2 + 5(-6) + 4=$

$(-6 + 1)(-6)^3 + 5(-6)^2 + 5(-6) + 4=$

$(-6)^4 + (-6)^3 + 5(-6)^2 + 5(-6) + 4=11554_{-6}$.

> I have also noticed that there seems to be 2 ways to write every number in a negative base, for example 3710 can be written as 177−10 or −43−10 and think there could be some way to use that to your advantage, although I still haven't gotten anywhere myself.

Yes that's true.  But I find the negative sign in front of a number that is ultimately positive confusing.

Note a negative sign in front of an even number of digits or a lack of negative sign in front of an odd number of digits means the number is positive (and vice versa).

Actually, that *could* be your rule.  All numbers in negative base are expressed with positive digits.  If the number has an even number of digits the number is positive  (as $neg^{highest\ even} > 0$ will overpower the number).  But if the number has an odd number of digits the number is negative (as $neg^{highest\ odd} < 0$ will overpower the numbers).